# struts1 DynaActionForm ClassNotFoundException

Tags: struts-1

I am learning Apache Struts1. When I use DynaActionForm, after submit '/login' request, an `ClassNotFoundException` error occurred: it can not find the action "com.wi.struts.UserAction". My file 'struts-config.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_2.dtd">
<struts-config>
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="UserForm" type="org.apache.struts.action.DynaActionForm">
             <form-property name="userName" type="java.lang.String"/>
             <form-property name="passWord" type="java.lang.String"/>
        </form-bean>
    </form-beans>

    <action-mappings>
        <action  path="/login"  type="com.wi.struts.UserAction" name="UserForm"  scope="session">
        <forward name="loginIn" path="index.jsp"/>
        </action>
    </action-mappings>

</struts-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking your deployed application .war or folder and check if you are exporting correctly all .class files of your project.

Good luck!